# Can this for loop be done with the preprocessor?

Tags: c++, templates, arduino, c-preprocessor, fastled

My code uses a library (FastLED) which uses a templated function:

```
#define NUM_WIDGETS 4

Library.function<1>();
Library.function<2>();
Library.function<3>();
Library.function<4>();
```

I can't put this in a normal for loop since the template argument needs to be computable at compile-time. Can I do this in the preprocessor? Any other suggestion? I'd like to be able to change NUM_WIDGETS conveniently without copy-pasting these lines.

Comment: look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence

Comment: Not preprocessor.  Recursive template.  `template<unsigned i> void invoke() {Library.function<i>(); invoke(i-1);};` with a specialisation to end the recursion `template<> void invoke<0U>() {};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using templates with the help of [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```
constexpr size_t NUM_WIDGETS = 4;

template <size_t N>
void foo() {
    std::cout << N << '\n';
}

template <size_t... Ns>
void call_foo_helper(std::index_sequence<Ns...>) {
    (foo<Ns>(), ...);
}

template <size_t N>
void call_foo() {
    call_foo_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
    call_foo<NUM_WIDGETS>();
}
```

This uses C++17 fold expressions.  If you don't have C++17 available, you could use a recursive template instead:

```
constexpr size_t NUM_WIDGETS = 4;

template <size_t N>
void foo() {
    std::cout << N << '\n';
}

template <size_t N>
void call_foo() {
    foo<N>();
    call_foo<N - 1>();
}

template <>
void call_foo<0>() { }

int main() {
    call_foo<NUM_WIDGETS>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fold expression based or recursive template solution is superior. But, if you wanted a preprocessor solution, you can see if your compiler provides the inclusion depth as a predefined macro. For example, GCC provides `__INCLUDE_LEVEL__` (and MSVC provides `__COUNTER__`). You can then use recursive inclusion up to a limit to generate your template function calls.

```
$ gcc -E r.cc | grep -v '^#' | sed '/^ *$/d'
int main()
{
   Library.function<1>();
   Library.function<2>();
   Library.function<3>();
   Library.function<4>();
}
$ cat r.cc
int main()
{
    #define NUM_WIDGETS 4
    #include "r.i"
}
$ cat r.i
#ifndef NUM_WIDGETS
# error "NUM_WIDGETS needs to be defined!"
#else
# if (__INCLUDE_LEVEL__) < ((NUM_WIDGETS) + 1)
   Library.function<__INCLUDE_LEVEL__>();
#  include __FILE__
# endif
#endif
```

This technique is limited to the nested inclusion limits of your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The template solutions in [Miles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371687/459640) are definitely the way to go.

But just for kicks, you can in fact also do it with the preprocessor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

template <int N> void function() { std::cout << N << "\n"; }

#define NUM_WIDGETS 4

int main()
{
#define CALL_FUNC(z,n,d) function<n+1>();
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(NUM_WIDGETS, CALL_FUNC, ~)
#undef CALL_FUNC
}
```

This isn't as good, because the count `NUM_WIDGETS` needs to be known to the preprocessor as a plain string of digits. Not `(4)`, not `4U`, not a `constexpr` variable, and so on.  And Boost.Preprocessor does have a limit of 256 repetitions (or slightly less if using MSVC).

Answer (score 1):

As I noted earlier in comment, it is easier to do this with templates than with preprocessor.

First define a template

```
 template<unsigned n> void invoke() {Library.function<n>();  invoke<n-1>();};
```

Then specialise an end condition that does nothing

```
 template<> void invoke<0U>() {};
```

and call it

```
 int main()
 {
      invoke<NUM_WIDGETS>();
 }
```

This will call the function in reverse order than specified.   That can be fixed by changing the template function to

```
 template<unsigned n> void invoke() {Library.function<NUM_WIDGETS + 1 - n>(); invoke<n-1>();};
```

and keeping the same specialisation to end the recursion.

Of course, if you need to do tricks like this (whether with the preprocessor or templates) that is suggestive of a broken design and you should be asking WHY `Library.function()` is a template in the first place.